# I currently know Calculus I -- What steps would I take to understand Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, philosophy

While this question can be discussed, it *should* have a clear answer by stating the following:

1. How can one go from a high school / low-level college understanding of mathematics (completed Calculus 1) to understand Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory?
2. Is this a large leap to make via self-study?

Regarding bullet point `1`, I struggle to find a step of paths to reach my goal (understanding ZF set theory) because I do not have the understanding to know what might be involved in the process, much like a monkey does not know what steps he can take to do algebra.

Regarding bullet point `2`, which may not have as precise an answer, how difficult is this step to make for an audodidactic?

The reason I ask this silly question is because I often find myself reading the *Philosophy of Mathematics* and the *Foundations of Mathematics* on Wikipedia and other websites.  This set theory comes up time and time again in these discussions, and I would like to better understand why it is so canonical.

Thank you.

Comment: There are no logical prerequisites to axiomatic set theory, so you can and should just jump in. That said, some intangible "mathematical maturity" is needed which is more easily gained from experience than from reading. Since you are self-studying, I suggest that at a minimum you carefully write up solutions to some exercises and ask others to judge them (harshly!). You can probably even do that here on math.stackexchange.

Comment: I would like to add: you should write up solutions to *all* exercises, especially since you're (I assume) new to rigorous proofwriting. Of course, you needn't share or ask for input on all such arguments, but for your own sake, you should do them nonetheless.

Comment: How can one get there? Slowly, with **a lot** of patience, and by working very hard.

Comment: I suggest you also : Kenneth Kunen, *The Foundations of Mathematics* (2009); in spite of the title is mainly an introduction to axiomatic set-theory.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but you should know that although modern mathematics can be founded upon ZFC set theory or suitable extensions, that does not at all imply that those are necessary or in any way privileged for foundational purposes. There have also been alternative foundational systems, including various type theories that historically trace back to Russell's theory of types designed to avoid his paradox, and a modern type theory is Martin Lof's, which is used in some proof assistants including the widely used Coq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get a book like [the one I self-studied from right after high school](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486616304).  It was outdated when I studied it but I thought it was precise and evocative, I guess it is still on the shelves in most B&N's and Borders.  Other Dover books too if you are down with the old school.
2. Certainly not, the only prerequisites are interest and dedication, with a dash of precision so you know what you think you know.  Calculus material isn't very relevant but some of your skills will transfer.  It will still be difficult, for me it was like a whole new way of thinking about math that was a lot more interesting than what I had learned in high school.

Comment: Another nice text is Enderton's "Elements of Set Theory", with a delightfully punny name.